# Where to put an excel file in a dynamic web project so that I can write and read it.(use it as DB)

Tags: java

I have a dynamic web project where I have login and register user and I am using POI to read and write the details in an excel file.

I want to deploy this project as WAR file on tomcat.

But the issue here is Tomcat is not able to find the excel file's path.

So where should I place the excel file.

Comment: Try to keep in tomcat's data folder

Comment: ... or perhaps any path you can write to (because you have permissions to), address it directly

Comment: @Marged I cannot keep a hardcoded path that's the whole issue.

Comment: @Surendar Kannan Could you please provide the path for tomcat data folder. I am new to tomcat so not sure

Comment: Use System.getProperty("CATALINA_HOME") to get tomcat home directory then append "data" with that.

Answer (score 0):

Right approach would be to

1. Make a directory on your OS outside of the tomcat.
2. Write a startup servlet which will check if the directory already exists.
3. If the directory exists, go ahead and create the excel file into that directory, instead of keeping an already build file, that way you make sure that the excel file is not tampered by any developer accidentally and is only constructed by the application.

Comment: I already have some 100 users So I cannot create a new File.And I don't know the directory structure of the system at which the WAR file is going to be deployed. So what I want is to integrate the excel within the WAR file

Comment: Then the only choice you have is to package your war so that your excel file gets packaged into the classes folder. One way would be to make a resources folder in your application directory structure and configure your build tool to copy the content of resource folder into the classes folder. If you are using maven it will automatically do it for you.